# Navigation from one component to another using Router in angular js

Tags: angular

Actually I am trying to navigate to Homepage_Component from Login_Component. I am using Spring Micro services as a back end for credential validation. It is validating credentials properly, so it should move to the Homepage_Component but it is still reloading the login_Component. When I checked in browser URL, the path(/coreapp) of Homepage_Component getting displayed but it is not loading Homepage_Component.
Here is my code:

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
import {MatCardModule} from '@angular/material/card';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { HomepageComponent } from './homepage/homepage.component';
import { RouterModule,Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './/app-routing.module';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
      { path: 'coreapp', component: HomepageComponent }
];
@NgModule({
declarations: [
  AppComponent,
  LoginComponent,
  HomepageComponent
],
imports: [
 RouterModule.forRoot(
    appRoutes  ,{ enableTracing: true }
),
 BrowserModule,
 HttpModule,
 FormsModule,
 MatCardModule,
 AppRoutingModule
],
providers: [
        ],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And this is login.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import {MatCardModule} from '@angular/material/card';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
   selector: 'app-login',
   templateUrl: './login.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],

})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private userservice : UserService,private router:Router) { }
    username2:string;
    token: string;
    title:string ="Activity Stream";
    public submitFunction(u:string,p:string): void {
        this.username2=u;
        alert("l");
        this.userservice.authenticate(u,p).subscribe(
        data => {
            if(data.status === 200) {
                localStorage.setItem('token',data.json().token);
                localStorage.setItem('username',u);
                this.token=data.json().token;
                this.router.navigate(['/coreapp']);
                location.reload();      
            }
        })
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your issue is the last line `location.reload`. So you are instructing the router to navigate to the new url but immediately after you are doing a reload of the same page.

If you remove that line your problem should be solved.

Comment: yeah even I thought the same, i tried that too but still no luck.

Comment: I’m assuming you have a router-outlet in the main page and you have the router configuration to handle the different routes, right?

Comment: yeah, thanks for the Router-Outlet. its working, but now homepage is opening below the login page

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the page html template? Need to check it

Comment: Well I don’t see the login bit on that source code. Anyway, on the router configuration I don’t see the path for login component. If the login is not a template with an associated route it won’t be replaced when you change the route.

Comment: That given link is demo one, in that I want to navigate to the home component from app component when user clicks on button. But when I click on button, it is just adding home component below of App component. How can I make them separate?

Comment: Well of course it is adding it below :). The way the router-outlet works is that it will inject content from your navigation route where the router-outlet tag is. If you want a different behaviour you need to have a main template which only contains the router outlet and all the content is injected by navigation. When you have a template like the one you have now on app component the content will always be appended on the router-outlet tag

Comment: @Hugo_Noro Thank you so much.

Comment: No worries always glad to help :)